# Evaluating convolution integral using scipy.quad

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, quad

I have a data set of {x2} values for which two arrays f[x2] and g[x2] are known. The data set {x2} is not uniformly spaced; and I would like to evaluate the convolution integral of f,g using these known samples. A minimal code for this would be something like:

```
#irregular grid for data points
x2  = np.geomspace( 5, 10, 100 )
x2n =-np.flip( x2 )
x2  = np.concatenate( ( x2n, x2 ) )
x2  = np.concatenate(  (np.array([0.0]) , x2 ), axis=0 )
x_inner = np.linspace( -5,5, 1000 )
x2 = np.concatenate( ( x_inner, x2 ) )    
x2  = np.sort(x2)
   
f2  = np.zeros( x2.shape[0], dtype=np.complex128 )
f2[ np.abs(x2)<=2 ] = 1.0 + 2j

g2 = np.zeros( x2.shape[0], dtype=np.complex128 )
g2 = np.sin( x2**3 )*np.exp( -x2**2 ) + 1j*np.sin( x2 )*np.exp( -x2**2 )      
           
def fg_x( f, g ):
    return f*g

def convolution_quad( f , g ):
    
    return quad(  fg_x, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(g)  )
    
    
from scipy.integrate import quad

#evaluate convolution of the two arrays over the irregular sample data x2
res2 = convolution_quad( f2, g2)
```

However, this function call does not work at all, it gives the error:

```
 return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
 TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

how can one calculate such convolution integrals over discrete data set by using scipy's quad? Such integrals can be evaluated with the trapezoid rule or Simpsons rule, but here I am looking for an accurate evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`quad` will require a continuous function as input.
Since your data is discrete you should use discrete convolution from
[numpy.convolve](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)

```py
res2 = np.convolve(f2, g2)
```

Comment: However, this approach seems to be wrong if the discretized data points do not lie on a linearly spaced grid, what if the data samples are not equidistant?

Comment: Assuming the sample is sufficiently fine, you can interpolate the signal and integrate the interpolation.